creating an sfn_network first merging linestrings
I am working on creating a spatial network in R where I need to consider several connected LINESTRINGs as a single line in the network. Each LINESTRING represents a segment of a rail network, and they are connected end-to-end. My goal is to simplify these connections so that the entire sequence of connected lines is treated as a single LINESTRING from start to end point.
Here is what my LINESTRINGs look like (each color represents a different LINESTRING):

However they have grouping Variable indicating which linestrings belong together (they touch each other at the ends)

So my aim is, that as sfn_network() not every single LINESTRING is considerered (with corresponding nodes) but at the end, the only the START/ END of the grouped LINESTRINGs are considered as nodes.
I tried something like:
rails1 <- rails %>% group_by(GROUP) %>% 
  summarise(do_union =TRUE)%>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")



 structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 7), ID_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7), GROUP = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(9.49750923562068, 9.25766974945376, 51.3143637469628, 
    51.1041822177009), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(9.25766974945376, 8.943977955227, 51.1041822177009, 
    51.0783319880388), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(8.943977955227, 8.773918358099, 51.0783319880388, 
    51.1867877726016), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(8.773918358099, 8.57243470497997, 51.1867877726016, 
    51.1786769084193), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(8.57243470497997, 8.56919987568677, 
    51.1786769084193, 51.144914596165), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
    "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(9.25766974945376, 9.36450576334242, 
    51.1041822177009, 50.9477904259333), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
    "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(9.36450576334242, 9.21755208973725, 
    50.9477904259333, 50.9058462470297), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
    "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
    input = "WGS 84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 8.56919987568677, 
ymin = 50.9058462470297, xmax = 9.49750923562068, ymax = 51.3143637469628
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(id = NA_integer_, 
ID_1 = NA_integer_, GROUP = NA_integer_), class = "factor", levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))


For the sample data given, lin_iden is 4 NA NA NA NA  9 NA NA NA  3. How can one group on that? Please adapt the sample data.

sorry adjusted should work with 14 now

To me this appears to be a xy-problem. Combining LINESTRINGS results in MULTILINESTRINGS, changing those to LINESTRINGS breaks thme in pieces again.

This looks wrong to me dplyr::summarise(rails, geometry = geometry |> sf::st_cast('MULTIPOINT') |> sf::st_union() |> sf::st_cast('LINESTRING'), .by = lin_iden) |> sfnetworks::as_sfnetwork() |> plot(). What is your overall goal? What is your expected output?

Not all of the lines for lin_iden == 3 are contiguous, so they currently cannot be joined. In particular, id == 16 and 46 do not touch. Is this a result of your sampling for your dput(), or do they not touch in your full data? If it's because of sampling, please provide a better example dataset. If they don't touch in your actual data, that's a bigger problem. My guess it's due to sampling, but please confirm.

Ok, thank you so much. I just checked and sadly the shp file I got is really corrupted. Still I really care about the question (also in other context), so I created a new shapefile, which should be compatible with the conditions and questions (but not necessarily with the pictures above). I update the dput.

As you now introduced a different set of variables (id, ID_1, GROUP) , please consider updating your plots and example code.

A combination of dplyr::summarise() and sf::st_line_merge() will achieve your desired outcome. Including directed = TRUE ensures only lines in the same direction (within each group in this reprex) are merged.
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


rails1 <- rails |>
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry), .by = GROUP) |>
  st_line_merge(directed = TRUE) |>
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

rails1
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: LINESTRING
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 8.5692 ymin: 50.90585 xmax: 9.497509 ymax: 51.31436
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   GROUP                       geometry
# 1     1 LINESTRING (9.497509 51.314...
# 2     2 LINESTRING (8.773918 51.186...
# 3     3 LINESTRING (9.25767 51.1041...

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = rails1, aes(colour = factor(GROUP))) +
  labs(colour = "GROUP") +
  theme_void()


